# Colors on screen are not exactly as defined in layout

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-color

I'm working on an app that can make screenshots. It draws a button on top of other apps to make a screenshot and when a screenshot is made, `view` is set to invisible. This view should not appear on the screenshot. Since there's some lag between setting the visibility and the view disappearing, I draw a few extra pixels and check for these pixels in the screenshot:

Layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:ignore="PxUsage,RtlHardcoded">

    <View
        android:layout_width="1px"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:background="#ff010203" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1px"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_marginTop="1px"
        android:background="#ff040506" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1px"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_marginTop="2px"
        android:background="#ff070809" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton 
        android:id="@+id/fab"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"

        app:icon="@drawable/ic_play"
        android:text="@string/start"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Initiating the layout:

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay, null)

val params = LayoutParams(
    windowType,
    FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE or FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE or flagsFullScreen,
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
)

view.layoutParams = params
windowManager.addView(marker, view)
```

Pressing the button, `MediaProjection` is started and my `Service` starts receiving frames. With the bitmap of the screenshot, I check for these pixels:

```
private fun isMarkerOnTop(screenshot: Bitmap, y: Int): Boolean {
     return screenshot.getPixel(0, y) == Color.rgb(1, 2, 3) &&
            screenshot.getPixel(0, y + 1) == Color.rgb(4, 5, 6) &&
            screenshot.getPixel(0, y + 2) == Color.rgb(7, 8, 9)
}
```

On my phone this works perfectly. On an emulator, colors can be just a bit oof. F.i. `screenshot.getPixel(0, 0)` returns `0xFF020304` instead of `0xFF010203`. If the layout color is changed, the bitmap color changes as well.

I suspected it to be some shadow drawn by the OS, but moving the layout always results in the first color being of just a small bit off. I could just ignore the first pixel, but who knows what happens on other devices. What could it be and how can it be solved robustly?